# (Beginner) SQL query throws up errors for no reason

Tags: mysql

I'm a beginner and have no idea what to do!
This is clearly not working
I'm using phpmyadmin importing code manually by hand from postgresql

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CUSTOMER (
     CUSTID              NUMERIC(6) NOT NULL,
     NAME                CHAR (45),
     ADDRESS             CHAR (40),
     CITY                CHAR (30),
     STATE               CHAR (2),
     ZIP                 CHAR (9),
     AREA                NUMERIC(3),
     PHONE               CHAR (9),
     REPID               NUMERIC(4) NOT NULL,
     CREDITLIMIT         NUMERIC(9,2),
     COMMENTS            TEXT,
     CONSTRAINT CUSTOMER_PRIMARY_KEY PRIMARY KEY (CUSTID));
     USE CUSTOMERS
     CONSTRAINT CUSTID_ZERO CHECK (CUSTID > 0)
```

SQL query:

USE CUSTOMERS
CONSTRAINT CUSTID_ZERO CHECK (CUSTID > 0)

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB >server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONSTRAINT CUSTID_ZERO CHECK (CUSTID > 0)' at line >2

Comment: the reason is you have to make an **ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER 
    ADD CONSTRAINT**  that what you have in invalid

Comment: MySQL normally uses INT types instead of NUMERIC without decimal places. So for the primary key you could use an UNSIGNED INT (or BIGINT) that would solve most of the CONSTRAINT (excluding the = 0) value. Note - https://dba.stackexchange.com/ is a better forum for DB queries that aren't programming.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the last line,

```
CONSTRAINT CUSTID_ZERO CHECK (CUSTID > 0)
```

Because when you declared CUSTID you already mentioned NOT NULL

Comment: The datatype NUMERIC can also be negative or 0 , this constraint would prohibit that in this table.

Comment: Ah my bad.  I thought its integer

Answer (score 0):

Changê you query to

```
ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER 
ADD CONSTRAINT CUSTID_ZERO CHECK (CUSTID > 0)
```

Comment: it sais "a new statement was found but not delimiter between it and previous one"

Comment: as you ca see i have not used **USE CUSTOMERS;** because it is only valid for Databases and not for tables. I tested it before hand on my 8.0.18 server and on dbfiddle and if works fine. Please read also danblacks comment to NUMERIC(6,0)  see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=83ed866c13ef1f6578aa8bddef526b6a